# Batch normalization: fixed samples or different samples by dimension?

Tags: multidimensional-array, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, batch-normalization

Some questions came to me as I read a paper 'Batch Normalization : Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift'.

In the paper, it says:

> Since m examples from training data can estimate mean and variance of
>   all training data, we use mini-batch to train batch normalization
>   parameters.

My question is :

Are they choosing m examples and then fitting batch norm parameters concurrently, or choosing different set of m examples for each input dimension?

E.g. training set is composed of `x(i) = (x1,x2,...,xn)` : n-dimension
for fixed batch `M = {x(1),x(2),...,x(N)}`, perform fitting all `gamma1~gamman` and `beta1~betan`.

vs

For `gamma_i`, `beta_i` picking different batch `M_i = {x(1)_i,...,x(m)_i}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to [machine learning, rather than software development](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found this question on cross-validated and data-science, so I can only answer it here. Feel free to migrate if necessary.

The mean and variance are computed for *all dimensions in each mini-batch at once*, using moving averages. Here's how it looks like in code in TF:

```
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(incoming, axis)
update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_mean, mean, decay)
update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(moving_variance, variance, decay)
with tf.control_dependencies([update_moving_mean, update_moving_variance]):
  return tf.identity(mean), tf.identity(variance)
```

You shouldn't worry about technical details, here's what's going on:

- First the `mean` and `variance` of the whole batch `incoming` are computed, along batch axis. Both of them are vectors (more precisely, tensors).
- Then current values `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` are updated by an `assign_moving_average` call, which basically computes this: `variable * decay + value * (1 - decay)`.

Every time batchnorm gets executed, it knows *one* current batch and some statistic of previous batches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so you mean one computes mean and variance of each mini-batch and do whitening(standard normalization) and shifting(multiply beta and add gamma) for every dimension. but why do we need to know some informations about previous batch? what do you mean by moving_mean and moving_variance?

Comment: @PeterKim that's a good question. Batchnorm tries to capture the mean and variance of the whole population, and moving average is an efficient way to do so, instead of storing all means and variances for all batches. There a good discussion about it here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219808/how-and-why-does-batch-normalization-use-moving-averages-to-track-the-accuracy-o

Comment: Thank you! so It's kind of moving  previously computed mean and variance 
toward population mean and variance with the information of new mini-batch. @Maxim